# PostgreSQL Output Formatting Newlines with Lists. What's the plus symbol mean?

Tags: bash, postgresql

Learning PostgreSQL here. I have a query in a bash script with a column title called "description." The cell will often have lists but the query output puts a + symbol before each list item. The plus symbols aren't in the cell contents. Why does it do this? How do I change this?

```
1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. + 2) Etiam vel magna vel nisi lobortis placerat rutrum vitae mi. + 3) Donec finibus purus sit amet enim faucibus sodales.
```

Comment: Please review [ask]. Following that as a template for  your question greatly enhances your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. As it stands your question lacks significant details: table description, the query, sample data, expected results.

Comment: Which SQL client are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using psql, '+' is the newline indicator:

```
create table long_lines(id int, fld_1 varchar, fld_2 boolean, fld_3 int, fld_4 varchar);

insert into long_lines values (1, 'First line\n New line', 't', 3, 'test');
select * from long_lines ;
 id |   fld_1    | fld_2 | fld_3 | fld_4 
----+------------+-------+-------+-------
  1 | First line+| t     |     3 | test
    |  New line  |       |       |
```

You can change the output:

```
\pset format csv
\pset t
Tuples only is on.

select * from long_lines ;
1,"First line
 New line",t,3,test
```

**UPDATE**: to show how above appears using Python script:

```
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test host=localhost user=aklaver")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from long_lines")
cur.fetchall()

[(1, 'First line\\n New line', True, 3, 'test')]
```

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL 12 on a mac. + newline indicator makes  perfect sense because I had a huge excel file where an editor created new lines for every numbered point in the "description" cell. I converted the excel file to a csv file and imported that into Postgres. I guess what I want is to insert \n instead of the + so that new lines are created in the output the bash script?

Comment: What you need to do is add the BASH script to your question. The '+' is a psql artifact that you are somehow picking up in the script. In psql it is just an alias/placeholder for \n. To see what happens in a Python script see my updated answer.